# Out of Memory with ListView

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am very familiar with OOM concept. I have come across so many questions that have been asked here and I know this could sound like a repeated question on OOM, but I have a different problem now.

I have hundreds and hundreds of images, which I have to show in a single `ListView` in a single `Activity`.

I have made use of the Fedor's lazy loading concept.

The code works fine when the images are little(something like 50-100 images), but if I get around 200 to 300 images, as soon as the user makes a scroll through the `ListView` (eventually) I am getting an out of memory exception.

I am using the efficient Adapter concept as shown [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) in developer site and I believe that this is the best custom adapter usage method.

All the suggestion what I have seen so far is based on reducing the bitmap size by scaling it or some other means. I have already tried those methods. But still the OOM occurs in some point of time.

Reducing the quality of the image doesn't look like the way to handle this Exception , because which seems to affect user experience and, also, it doesn't work for a large amount of bitmaps.

My questions here are:

1. How do you display `n` images in a single `ListView` without facing OOM?
2. What are the best strategies to follow in this scenario?
3. Is it possible to show around 500 images in a single `ListView`?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your code and the error you got?
I had the same error, few days ago. Are you using an URI to set your image? Regards.

Comment: No I am downloading it by means of APIs at run time

Comment: sorry for the silly question but do you keep in memory all the 500 images?

Comment: No. I dont want to keep it in memory. I save it to the sdcard using the lazy loading concept.

Comment: do you use same kind of cache to keep the bitmap in memory?

Answer (score 0):

1. Look into googles shelvesproject.
2. Shelvesproject does following: uses a placeholder image while loading image, use weakreference for storring images, delayed handler updated with clearing.
3. Yes and no, it is possible to have listview with this many items but its not possible to have this many images all in memory at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try with API Level 11+ images before this API Level are placed in application heap. And yes it is possible to have a List View with a 500 images and working smooth (Contacts application for example).

This http://code.google.com/p/android-imagedownloader/ may help you getting images, cache and recycle them.